# Facelets dataTable to iterate through all the objects's attributes

Tags: jsf

I have a list of objects where I don't know how many, or what the attributes will be called. Can I create a dataTable to display all the objects's attributes in different columns?

I was thinking at something like:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.objectList}" var="object">
    <ui:repeat value="#{object.getAllAttributes}" var="attribute">
       <h:column>"#{object.attribute}"</h:column>
    </ui:repeat>
</h:dataTable>
```

Is something like this doable? Does facelets has a way to display all the attributes?

Comment: *Is something like this doable?* try it before posting it as question :).

Answer (score 1):

I think it is perfectly doable, although I did not try this scenario, but I tried something similar, have a look [here](http://blog.petruescu.net/programming/jsf/using-facelets-technology-(part-II)/).
For eample, this custom component ::

```
<custom:customTable
   id="my-dynamic-table"
   pojoList="#{myBean.somePojoList}"  
   pojoProperties="property3,property4,property5,property6"
</custom:customTable>
```

is being passed the properties (attributes) to be invoked on each target pojo.